# How to share the file names of all the files in a folder in Android?

Tags: file-management, backup

It is being surprisingly hard to achieve. I've tried so far:

- Download file manager apps from Google Play. Unfortunately, "share" shares the files, not the file names. None of them had a option like copy file names
- Download backup apps. Unfortunately, none of them backup the file names of a folder.

Any idea to copy to the clipboard or share the file names of all the files of a folder?

Comment: The currently written query is not acceptable for SoftRecs.SE. You should follow [their guideline](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to make it on-topic on there.

Comment: @AndrewT. I already wrote the question on Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. They say it was not acceptable for Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. They asked me to ask the question on SoftRecs.SE. So I did. Now, you guys has migrated the question back to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, so it has been marked as duplicated. This is remembering me the bureaucracy / public system xD

Comment: FWIW, the question you asked on Android.SE is on-topic (otherwise, it'd had been closed). However, for explicit app recommendations, SoftRecs.SE is more suitable, but the question must have *clear criteria* of what kind of apps you're trying to find, like "straightforward to be used by elderly people" or something. Otherwise, there's nothing we can't do to help either.